# How to make responsive tables in ionic 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im populating dynamic data using ionic 2 & angular here im getting and displaying the data but im getting table in non responsive format and below is my code

```
  <ion-grid>
<ion-row style="padding-top:5px;paddind:bottom:5px;background:#488aff">
  <ion-col>
   A
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
   B
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row *ngFor="let value of resultData" style="background:#eff0f1">
  <ion-col>
    {{value.A}}
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    {{value.b}}
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

[image: Below is my table and it is not responsive]

Comment: Refer this link http://plnkr.co/edit/GdMQ84?p=preview

Comment: Did not get your question. there is nothing wrong with you code.maybe you put some of your code here.